# Calculate ECDSA public key from private key in native java without BouncyCastle

Tags: java, cryptography

Plenty of solutions here discuss how to derive the ECDSA public key from its private key, *using BouncyCastle*. I'm looking for a solution in plain java >= 11.

ChatGPT suggests this:

```java
    // Get the parameters of the private key
    ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ((ECPrivateKey) privateKey).getParams();
    
    // Generate a public key using the private key parameters
    ECPoint Q = ecSpec.getGenerator().multiply(privateKey.getS());
    ECPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(Q, ecSpec);
    
    // Get a KeyFactory object that can generate EC public keys
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    
    // Generate the public key
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
```

But [`java.security.spec.ECPoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/spec/ECPoint.html) does not offer a `multiply()` method, unlike [`org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint`](https://bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.8on/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/ECPoint.html#multiply-java.math.BigInteger-). I'd like to stick to native Java without BC, if possible. What can I do?

Comment: This is not a regular multiplication, but an [elliptic curve point multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication). BC implements this, JCA/JCE does not (at least does not expose public methods for this), as far as I know. Implementing this with plain Java (i.e. without third-party libraries like BC) is probably comparatively costly (at least if you want it to be efficient and secure).

Comment: @Topaco thank you - happy for you to post this as an answer